Crashes logged from usage of IOPSGetPowerSourceDescription in iOS app
With our iOS app we've seen pretty steep increased crashes on iOS 15 devices from uses of this API: IOPSGetPowerSourceDescription
The weird thing is our app does not use this API. As per the docs, the API is only available for macOS. I'm suspecting iOS maybe is using this under the hood somehow, or perhaps some framework is trying to use it somehow. Is anyone else seeing this?
Because of the increased crashes (we've seen this occasionally before), this might qualify for a bug report to Apple.
